# Force a user in Meteor to relogin through the OAuth provider

Tags: meteor

I want to be able to force a use to relogin using the OAuth provider. I have tried deleting the services.resume.loginTokens, I tried deleting the AuthKey under the service itself in services.myService.accessToken but nothing works.

I also have searched through the OAuth package and looked at all the Accounts packages, but cannot find any code that allows me to force the user to relogin with the OAuth provider.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: if the service you are using is facebook there is an option that forces the user to re-enter his password. If you are interested I can post an answer with screen captures?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has a login token, which is usually kept in the browser's local storage. This has a life of 3 months, and is how Meteor keeps the user logged in. If you simply call

```
Meteor.logout();
```

It will log the user out. If your routes check that the user is logged in, they will be forced to log in again

Comment: I think you do not understand my question. When a user logs out of the application I want him to log in again Using the OAuth provider which happens in the app with a redirect. 

User is logged in. -> user clicks logout. -> user want to log back in -> clicks login button. -> now he goes to the OAuth provider logs in and gets redirected back to the app.

Currently the user click log in and is back in the app. What if someone else uses that computer now? 

That is the reason why I want to force the user to log in again using OAuth.